# Do I need to register a TemplateVariableResolver somehow?

Tags: java, eclipse, templates, plugins

I'm trying to write a simple template variable resolver extension that for now should just insert a random UUID but for some reason my variable does not show up in the list when I click Insert Variable in the template definition in the Preferences menu under Java->Editor->Templates.

I'm thinking that I need to register the resolver class somehow but I've found no information online indicating that I should need to do that.

I have a plugin project and it shows up in the list of installed plugins in Eclipse.

My resolver extends SimpleTemplateVariableResolver and looks like this:

```
public class UUIDTemplateVariableResolver extends SimpleTemplateVariableResolver {

protected UUIDTemplateVariableResolver() {
    super("randomuuid", "Get random UUID");
}

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    protected String resolve(final TemplateContext context) {
        return UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }
}
```

I've added the extension point in plugin.xml as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>
    <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.editors.templates">
        <resolver class="se.wdi.hamtauuid.UUIDTemplateVariableResolver"
            contextTypeId="java"
            description="Generates a random UUID"
            name="Get UUID" type="randomuuid"/>
    </extension>
</plugin>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Which preference page? This is extension point is for the 'Java > Editor > Templates' page.

Comment: @greg-449 That's the one I meant, I've edited to clarifiy that.